# Display external data in SharePoint-style lists style using the Javascript Object Model

Tags: client-object-model

I have a webservice which provides me with tabular data, which I would like to display in SharePoint in the typical SharePoint-List way. 
Now I could simple copy the html and styles and build the tables and context-menus etc. from scratch, but I'm hoping that there's some (well)hidden feature of javascript OM which will make this easier for me.

Is this possible? Does anyone have pointers or examples for this approach?

P.S. I don't want to do this server side. That would be too easy :)

Update:
I'm trying to integrate an existing LOB Application into SharePoint. this application offers a restful webservice API. The Main reason I want to use the Client Side OM IS ease of Development, deployment and Maintenance. As the existing App is a product which will be installed in many different Client Szenarios, having a Solution which has very little impact on the Infrastructure is a big plus.

Comment: I'd suggest that you include a description of your motives for doing this as it might be easier to suggest some other possibilities for you rather than just BCS or COM. Sometimes when we have a problem we focus on one way of solving it that is not optimal and if a third party understand why we are trying to do something they can suggest a better way that we were unable to see because we have focused on one way of solving the problem.

Comment: Updated motivation

Comment: This isn't really a COM question. Really it just comes down to skinning and using JavaScript (JQuery or some other library would ease development) and using the SharePoint CSS to style it the way you want. The JavaScript would get the data and then you would use the proper CSS to display the controls and HTML it produced in the way you want.

Comment: that's what I meant "with copying the html and styles and building it from scratch.." I was hoping there'd be some OM objects and methods which would make it building the tables a lot easier..

Comment: That's not really the purpose of the client object model, though. COM is about performing CRUD operations on SharePoint objects and data. There may be a JavaScript library for simplifying the creation of HTML, but the COM is not it.

Comment: that may have been the purpose, but it does offer UI functionality as well. e.g. adding webparts or extending the ribbon.

Comment: And those are SharePoint objects. Your external data is not.

Answer (score 1):

If coding is an option, take a look at the [SPGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview.aspx). I think you could achieve what you want with a sandboxed solution.

Going the client only route is feasable, but difficult, as SharePoint generates a boatload of markup, styles and scripts to get everything working.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create [BDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231515.aspx). Then you can create external list. It works and looks like sharepoint list, but have several [limitations](http://www.layer2.de/en/community/FAQs/BDLC/Pages/Feature-comparision-sharepoint-external-list.aspx).

Comment: I only have SharePoint Foundation to work with, and using BDC is to much configurative hassle anyway.

Comment: BCS is included in SharePoint Foundation and it's not that much trouble to configure. It is certainly less difficult to configure than writing anything but the least trivial JavaScript for the COM.

Answer (score 0):

I know you won't like this, but if you cannot use SPGridView, look at JQuery Template. This would help you more easily create the UI.

http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/